# How to create a border shadow inset

Tags: css, photoshop

[image]

How to create a border shadow inset as in the above image

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kbwd/)

```
<div id="progress-bar">
  <div id="bar"></div>                        
</div>

#progress-bar {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#bar {
    width: 97%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #eeebf1;
    border-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the css box-shadow property : [Box Shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)

```
#bar {
width: 97%;
height: 20px;
background-color: #eeebf1;
border-radius: 9px;
-moz-border-radius: 9px;
-webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 3px #CCC inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #CCC inset;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #CCC inset;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8kbwd/2/

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot...

```
.shadow {
   -moz-box-shadow-top:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow-top: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow-top:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```